# uncaught type error when i am viewing a variable in html using the .innerHTML function

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to view one of my variables in a html page, I see nothing. If I open the console, I see this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property ‘innerHTML’ of null at my-java-script.js:17.

My script is quite simple.  Here are the codes:
my-java-script.js:

```
var c = 3+4;
console.log(“The value of c is”, c);
var x=6 ;
var y=3;
var s = x-y ;
console.log(“Subtraction of” , x , “and” , y , “is”, s);
var m = x*y ;
console.log(“Multiplication of”, x , “and” , y , “is”, m);
var a = x+y ;
console.log(“Addition of”, x , “and” , y , “is”, a);
var d = x/y ;
console.log(“Division of”, x , “and” , y , “is”, d);

var ao = (x*y +10)/4;
console.log(ao);
var myVariable = “HELLO”;
document.getElementById(“demo”).innerHTML = myVariable;
```

my-java-webpage.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Webpage </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "my-java-script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1> Java script</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a pic of the console and the webpage:
 [pic of the console and the webpage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/016TY.png)

Comment: try placeing `<script type="text/javascript" src = "my-java-script.js"></script>` inside the html body, now you are trying to access the `demo` element before it is actually loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because " " is not used properly also try to use the script in the body just closing

```js
      var c = 3+4;
      console.log("The value of c is", c);
      var x=6 ;
      var y=3;
      var s = x-y ;
      console.log("Subtraction of" , x , "and" , y , "is", s);
      var m = x*y ;
      console.log("Multiplication of", x , "and" , y , "is", m);
      var a = x+y ;
      console.log("Addition of", x , "and" , y , "is", a);
      var d = x/y ;
      console.log("Division of", x , "and" , y , "is", d);

      var ao = (x*y +10)/4;
      console.log(ao);
      var myVariable = "HELLO";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myVariable;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Avengers Avenue</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Java script</h1>

    <p id="demo"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "my-java-script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```